# How to avoid the following repeated code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, optimization, webclient

I wrote two functions which look similar, how can I optimize them?

Note:

1.`AsyncCompletedEventArgs` is the base class of `DownloadStringCompletedEventArg` and `UploadStringCompletedEventArgs`.

2.`Result` property is not in the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`.

3.`DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs` has a `Error` property, if `Error` is `null`, then try to access `Result` property, the exception occurs.

```
void fun1(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string s = e.Result;
    }
    catch (WebException eX)
    {
        HandleWebException();
    }
}

void fun2(UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       string s = e.Result;
   }
   catch (WebException eX)
   {
       HandleWebException();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have try..catch around a simple assignment?

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all: (1) You are assigning a value to an unused local variable (2) You have a try catch block around a statement that won't throw (except the implementation of `e.Result` doesn't conform to the convention to not throw from property getters...

Comment: so we are safe to say that these handlers are transparent ones and you can optimize out the whole question by not writing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UploadStringCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadstringcompletedeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [`DownloadCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) both extend [`AsyncCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tde67e9%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but unfortunately the base class does not define the `Result` property.

A *TryX* pattern with a result accessor delegate might be appropriate here:

```
public bool TryGetResult(Func<string> resultAccessor, out string result)
{
    try
    {
        result = resultAccessor();
        return true;
    }
    catch(WebException)
    {
        HandleWebException();

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}

void fun1(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)      
{
    string result;
    if (TryGetResult(() => e.Result, out result))
    {
        // Success
    }
}      

void fun2(UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)      
{      
    string result;
    if (TryGetResult(() => e.Result, out result))
    {
        // Success
    }
}
```

I'd recommend trying to work in a check to [AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), though, as exceptions are quite expensive.

Answer (score 4):

You code may be changed to something like below:

```
    void fun1(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) { Process(e); }

    void fun2(UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) { Process(e); }

    private void Process(dynamic eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = eventArgs.Result;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            HandleWebException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work... the exception will be thrown in `Process(e.Result);` not in `Process`

Comment: It is the access to `*StringCompletedEventArgs.Result` that throws the exception so the above code will still fail.

Comment: @the_joric Maybe the keyword **dynamic** can solve this problem. I will try it tommorrow when i come back to the company.

Comment: i work on windows phone 7 using .net 3.5 which donot support dynamic keyword. Anyway, it works for .net 4.0, so mark the answer as acception.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
void fun1(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var result = Process<string>(e); 
    if (result != null)
    {
        // TODO your logic here
    }
}

void fun2(UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    var result = Process<string>(e); 
    if (result != null)
    {
        // TODO your logic here
    }
}

private T Process<T>(AsyncCompletedEventArgs result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
        HandleWebException(result.Error);
    else if (!result.Cancelled)
    {
        //var prop = result.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
        //return (T) prop.GetValue(result, null);
        return (T) ((dynamic)result).Result;
    }
    //else // TODO handle cancelled
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: `var prop = result.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
        return (T) prop.GetValue(result, null);`
can be changed to `return ((dynamic)result).Result;`

Comment: Yes, nice... :-) I think it should be: `return (T) ((dynamic)result).Result;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write a function that takes a parameter of type AsyncCompletedEventArgs (from which both eventArg classes you use inherit) and then attempt to cast it to the correct type in your code. That would allow you to complete both in the same method, but looking at your code it probably wouldn't have much benefit for you. Good luck!